# The App stops when in background mode

Tags: android, cordova, background, native-code

My app stops when I leave it. 
I don't know why. Infact I know that the default  action is to Keep it running.
Maybe could be the nfc plugin tha i use in it?
Where can i control the native code for this behaviour?

Comment: How do you know that it stops?

Comment: Post the stack trace pleas.

Comment: It restarts when i click on it.

Comment: can you give me the adb command to get the stack trace please?

Answer (score 1):

in `AndroidManifest.xml` add `configChanges` parameter like this:

```
    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        ...
        />
```

Then activity will not be recreated every time on resume.

Comment: This is my activity:                                        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="HelloCordova" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:
add to

> AndroidManifest.xml

activity this :

> android:launchMode="singleTask"